# Boolean Expression simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, boolean-computation

I'm stuck in proving `(A+B+C+D)(A′+B′+C′+D′)=AD′+A′B+C′D+B′C` using algebraic manipulation. I tried to solve it. I expanded `(A+B+C+D)(A′+B′+C′+D′)`, and I got:

```
AD′+BD′+CD′+BA′+CA′+DA′+AC′+BC′+DC′+AB′+CB′+DB′
```

But I don't know how to proceed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this about *Mathematics* or about *Wolfram Mathematica programming*? you may be in the wrong forum.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit with A' meaning Not[A]

(*Thanks to Carl Woll for pointing out that `A'` means `Not[A]`.*)

Here is the proof using [`BooleanTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanTable.html). I replaced the symbols A,B,C,D with A0,B0,C0,D0. I also replaced the `Plus` and `Times` infix forms with `||` and `&&` respectively.

```
t = 
 BooleanTable[
  {(A0 || B0 || C0 || D0) && (Not[A0] || Not[B0] || Not[C0] || Not[D0]), 
   A0 && Not[D0] || Not[A0] && B0 || Not[C0] && D0 || Not[B0] && C0 },
  {A0, B0, C0, D0}]

(* {{False, False}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {False, False}} *)

Tally[t]

(* {{{False, False}, 2}, {{True, True}, 14}} *)
```

### Original answer

What you are trying to prove does not seem to be true.

Here is code to show that using [`BooleanTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanTable.html). I replaced the symbols A,B,C,D with A0,B0,C0,D0 and the symbols A',B',C',D' with A1,B1,C1,D1. I also replaced the `Plus` and `Times` infix forms with `||` and `&&` respectively.

```
t = BooleanTable[
    {(A0 || B0 || C0 || D0) && (A1 || B1 || C1 || D1), 
     A0 && D1 || A1 && B0 || C1 && D0 || B1 && C0 }, 
    {A0, B0, C0, D0, A1, B1, C1, D1}];
Short[t]

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, 
  True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, <<241>> {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, 
  False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}} *)

Tally[t]

(* {{{True, True}, 175}, {{False, False}, 31}, {{True, False}, 50}} *)
```

Comment: A' means Not[A]

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you pointing that out!